# Как в андроиде задать путь для сохранения файла?

Tags: java, android

Как задать путь сохранения для загруженного файла, чтобы открылся диспетчер файлов и можно было указать папку для сохранения?

Научился загружать файлы, отображать процесс, открывать после загрузки.
Научился сохранять задавая путь в виде:

```
output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/my_downloads8.pdf");
```

Файл в формате пдф.

Пример взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) .

Спасибо за любую информацию.
Весь мой код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


    //defining file name and url
//    public String fileName = "человек бренд";
//    public String fileURL = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_Vo7XGE5XkUTXUwbDdQY1BKT2c";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("A message");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
// execute this when the downloader must be fired
                final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(MainActivity.this);
                downloadTask.execute("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_Vo7XGE5XkUTXUwbDdQY1BKT2c");

                mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        downloadTask.cancel(true);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // usually, subclasses of AsyncTask are declared inside the activity class.
// that way, you can easily modify the UI thread from here
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        private Context context;
        private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

        public DownloadTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
                // instead of the file
                if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                            + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                }

                // this will be useful to display download percentage
                // might be -1: server did not report the length
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                input = connection.getInputStream();
                //output = new FileOutputStream("/my_downloads88");
                output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/my_downloads8.pdf");

                byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    // allow canceling with back button
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }

                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }

        void downloadAndOpenPDF() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/my_downloads8.pdf"));
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user
            // presses the power button during download
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    getClass().getName());
            mWakeLock.acquire();
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            if (result != null)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Download error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
            downloadAndOpenPDF();
                Toast.makeText(context, "File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот тут посмотрите https://github.com/lemberg/directory-selector-dialog-preference